# Exported library not visible in other modules

Tags: flutter, dart

There's a library called [collection](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) which adds lots of functionalities to dart's `List` and `Iterable` API.

I wanted to build upon it and create a couple of my own utility functions, like `mapNotNull`:

```dart
extension IterableExtension<E> on Iterable<E> {
  Iterable<T> mapNotNull<T extends Object>(T Function(E event) f) =>
      map((e) => f(e)).whereNotNull();
}
```

In order to make all extensions visible via a single import, I've created a new library, exported my extension and added at the top:

```dart
// in core_utils module, in iterable_extension.dart file
export 'package:collection/collection.dart';
```

But after I import this library in other package, API from `collection` library is missing. How do I fix that?

```dart
import 'package:core_utils/core_utils.dart';

void main() {
  [].mapNotNull((event) => 1); // compiles
  [].none((e) => false); // compilation error
}
```

The error message isn't really helpful:

```
The method 'none' isn't defined for the type 'List'. (Documentation)  
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'none'.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because extension names are colliding.

Rename

```
extension IterableExtension<E> on Iterable<E> {
```

to for example

```
extension IterableExt<E> on Iterable<E> {
```